# BottomNavigation jumps after back from other screen

Tags: android, android-layout

When app started it shows layout correctly. But if i go to other screen and then press back then BottomNavigationView will be shown partly below the screen.

[image: bottom navigation]

Sometimes when you click the screen it jumps back.

[image: normal state]

When i add bottom margin to BottomNavigation i can see how it jumps. Looks like it's bottom margin changed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>        
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/toolbar"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:elevation="8dp"
                app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black"
                app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
                app:menu="@menu/main" />

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/stateLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigation">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/listPosts"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_post" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: try `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on your root layout

Comment: I added it to ConstraintLayout. It didn't helped.

Comment: what about adding it under `<layout>` tag

Comment: did you made any changes in styles.xml?

Comment: styles.xml is default. Adding of android:fitsSystemWindows to <layout> didn't helped too.